# SMB on Windows Server 2008 R1 via Powershell

Tags: windows, powershell, powershell-2.0, windows-server-2008-r2, smb

I am trying to use Powershell on a Windows Server 2008 R1 computer using the following command:

```
Get-SmbServerConfiguration
```

Per my understanding this also works on W2K8, not on W2K12 only. However I receive the following error:

**The term 'Get-SmbServerConfiguration' is not recognized as the name of a cmdlet, function, script file, or operable program. Check the spelling of the name, or if a path was included, verify that the path is
 correct and try again.
At line:1 char:27
+ Get-SmbServerConfiguration <<<<

    + CategoryInfo          : ObjectNotFound: (Get-SmbServerConfiguration:String) [], CommandNotFoundException
    + FullyQualifiedErrorId : CommandNotFoundException**

So I added the related cmdlet:

```
Import-Module Smb*
```

But this ended in an error too:

**Import-Module : The specified module 'Smb*' was not loaded because no valid module file was found in any module directory.
At line:1 char:14
+ Import-Module <<<<  Smb*
    + CategoryInfo          : ResourceUnavailable: (Smb*:String) [Import-Module], FileNotFoundException
    + FullyQualifiedErrorId : Modules_ModuleNotFound,Microsoft.PowerShell.Commands.ImportModuleCommand**

So what is the problem here?

By the way: The Powershell version is 2.0.

Tia, Joey

Answer (score 0):

The problem was the version of Sophos: Installing a tighly newer one fixed the issue.